# appium desktop and Inspector problem. They won't work together

Tags: xcode, testing, mobile, automation, appium

I am experiencing an issue with appium desktop, appium inspector and xcode.  For the sake of speed [I've done a video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xhwatr5fx80viq0/stackoverflow%20Question.mp4?dl=0)

I'm getting the following error message and I would appreciate some help fixing it I am getting the following error:

[image]

From Appium Inspector:

```
    {
  "platformName": "iOS",
  "appium:platformVersion": "15.2",
  "appium:automationName": "XCUItest",
  "appium:deviceName": "iPhone 13",
  "appium:debugLogSpacing": true,
  "appium:bundleId": "com.apple.Preferences"
}
```

What can I do to resolve this because I am totally at a loss right now.

Comment: I've spoken to a colleague and modified the json.  See above

Answer (score 0):

I was able to update the desired capabilities

```
{
  "platformName": "iOS",
  "appium:platformVersion": "15.2",
  "appium:automationName": "XCUItest",
  "appium:deviceName": "iPhone 13",
  "appium:debugLogSpacing": true,
  "appium:bundleld": "com.apple.Preferences"
}
```